Wudhu before Prophet Muhammed sws
Did Prophets before Prophet Muhammed sws do wudhu and if they did do we have evidence proof?

There is disagreement on this. The view of the majority of the scholars is that wudu was also part of the laws of the previous prophets. The evidence for that includes the ahadith:

هاجر إبراهيم بسارة، دخل بها قرية فيها ملك من الملوك أو جبار من الجبابرة، فأرسل إليه أن أرسل إلى بها‏.‏ فأرسل بها، فقام إليها فقامت توضأ وتصلي فقالت اللهم إن كنت آمنت بك وبرسولك فلا تسلط على الكافر، فغط حتى ركض برجله
(The Prophet) Abraham migrated with his wife Sarah till he reached a town where there was a king or a tyrant who sent a message, to Abraham, ordering him to send Sarah to him. So when Abraham had sent Sarah, the tyrant got up, intending to do evil with her, but she got up and performed ablution and prayed and said, 'O Allah ! If I have believed in You and in Your Apostle, then do not empower this oppressor over me.' So he (the king) had an epileptic fit and started moving his legs violently. "
— Bukhari


كان رجل في بني إسرائيل ... وكان جريج في صومعته، فقالت امرأة لأفتنن جريجا‏.‏ فتعرضت له فكلمته فأبى، فأتت راعيا، فأمكنته من نفسها فولدت غلاما، فقالت هو من جريج‏.‏ فأتوه، وكسروا صومعته فأنزلوه وسبوه، فتوضأ وصلى ثم أتى الغلام، فقال من أبوك يا غلام قال الراعي‏.‏ قالوا نبني صومعتك من ذهب‏.‏ قال لا إلا من طين
There was a man from the Bani  Israel called Juraij ... Juraij used to live in a hermitage. A woman said that she would entice Juraij, so she went to him and presented herself (for an evil act) but he refused. She then went to a shepherd and allowed him to commit an illegal sexual intercourse with her and later she gave birth to a boy. She alleged that the baby was from Juraij. The people went to Juraij and broke down his hermitage, pulled him out of it and abused him. He performed ablution and offered the prayer, then he went to the male (baby) and asked him; "O boy! Who is your father?" The baby replied that his father was the shepherd. The people said that they would build for him a hermitage of gold but Juraij asked them to make it of mud only."
— Bukhari

